# Как в Google Maps строить маршрут между точкой и областью?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Здравствуйте.
Задача: построить маршрут от точки до полигона на Картах Google.
Нашел информацию только о том, как построить маршрут между двумя точками, но с областью есть нюанс: маршруты до неё могут быть разными в зависимости от того, какую её точку считать конечной. Есть ли стандартный способ построения подобных маршрутов?

Comment: в `Google Maps` построение `route` возможно только от точки до точки, с возможностью добавления промежуточных точек.

Comment: Как в таком случае найти координаты второй точки?

Comment: полигон состоит из точек, оттуда и берите

Answer (score 1):

Без математики тут не обойтись. Необходимо определить центр масс вашего полигона. Для расчета можно воспользоваться формулами с [сайта](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/gravity_center). Определив точку можно построить PolyLine, предоставляемый GoogleMaps API.

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно не центральная точка массива, а ближайшая

Comment: Можно решить следующим образом - зная центральную точку (ноходящуюся в полигоне) и начальную точку, можно построить отрезок. Далее можно найти точку пересечения отрезка и ближайшей грани, это и будет ближайшая точка)